# calculate a 3-Bytes CRC using Nucleo L053R8 CRC calculation unit

Tags: c, crc, nucleo

I would like to calculate a 3bytes CRC value using the crc calculation unit of the Nucleo L053R8.
The generator Polynomial is the following: g(X)=x^24 + x^10 + x^9 + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1

It seems that using this CRC calculation unit I can only generate a 32bits length CRC and smaller values are just the LSBS of the 32bit result.
I also know that the LSB of CRC32 in not equal to a CRC16.

Any idea on what operations I should perform on the input/output data to get the correct CRC24 I want ?

Comment: If you want a CRC-24 then why are you using the polynomial for CRC-16-CCITT?

Comment: I am generating a crc for a BLE  packet and got this polynomial from the official specification of Bluetooth, But I guess you are right I might misunderstood

Comment: i still need hints to know how to get this right

Comment: I know very little of this, but I believe BLE uses some 24 bit CRC, maybe like this one? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/90472/how-can-i-implement-bluetooth-low-energy-crc-in-24-bits

Comment: yes thanks for drawing my attention I was referring to the wrong section now I have the correct polynomial I assume how can I proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply the generator polynomial by x^8, by shifting it left 8 bits. If you have an initial value, also multiply it by x^8, by shifting it left 8 bits. Use the 32 bit CRC code with the shifted polynomial and initial value, then shift the resulting 32 bit CRC right by 8 bits.

```
g(X)*x^8 = x^32 + x^18 + x^17+ x^14 + x^12 + x^11 + x^9 + x^8
```

Comment: and what about the init value it is 0x555555 ?

Comment: @Abyr - multiply the init value by x^8 also, in this case 0x555555 * x^8 = 0x55555500 .